# Can I use the hashes in a HashMap directly?

Tags: rust

Is it possible to insert and get values into/from a [`HashMap`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.HashMap.html) directly with a [`Hash`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/hash/trait.Hash.html) provided, so I can cache the hashes?

I want to do something like this:

```
map.insert(key, "value");

let hashed_key = {
    let mut hasher = map.hasher().build_hasher();
    key.hash(&mut hasher);
    hasher.finish()
};

assert_eq!(map.get(key).unwrap(), map.get_by_hash(hashed_key).unwrap());
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=0cf098be07b08369121fa0de558a3f34&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015)

Comment: There is the function [`search_hashed_nonempty`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/std/collections/hash/map.rs.html#427), but of course it's not public :|

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**No.**

This is fundamentally impossible at the algorithmic level.

By design, a hash operation is **surjective**: multiple elements may hash to the same value. Therefore, any HashMap implementation can only use the hash as a *hint* and must then use a *full equality comparison* to check that the element found by the *hint* is the right element (or not).

At *best*, a `get_by_hash` method would return an `Iterator` of all possible elements matching the current hash.

For a degenerate case, consider a hashing algorithm which always returns `4` (obtained by the roll of a fair dice). Which element would you expect it to return?

---

**Work-around**

If *caching* is what you are after, the trick in languages with no `HashBuilder` is to pre-hash (and cache) the hash inside the key itself.

It requires caching the full key (because of the equality check), but hashing is then a very simple operation (return the cached value).

It does not, however, speed up the equality check, which depending on the value may be quite expensive.

You could adapt the pattern to Rust, although you would lose the advantage of using a `HashBuilder`.

Comment: Thanks, I forgot about the equality check. However wouldn't it be possible to provide the `Hash` **and** the key for a potential faster lookup? Assuming you are using the same `HashBuilder`

Comment: @Tim: In the current implementation, it could possibly be made available. However, there is a DOS-prevention scheme for hash maps which consists in changing the hash seed on growth (which immediately invalidates all cached hashes), and exposing the internal hash for caching would make this DOS-prevention implementation impossible, so I'm not sure if anyone would be comfortable adding this. On the other hand, the work-around I described is immune to this issue and provides the caching you seek.

Comment: Alright, the DOS-prevention scheme makes sense and it's probably good, that it's not a public interface so the internal may change.